# What could be the reason for http requests via NodeJS to 127.0.0.1 getting ECONNREFUSED?

Tags: node.js

I start a simple web server on `127.0.0.1:8000`:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

I can make a http request with curl from the terminal successfully

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8000

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
<body>
<h2>Directory listing for /</h2>
<hr>
<ul>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

When I make a http request from NodeJS I get `ECONNREFUSED`.

```
const axios = require('axios');

(async function init() {
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        });
        console.log("response", response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("error", error);
    }
})()
```

What could be the reason for this?

Additional information

- I have tried with `http`, `axios` and `node-fetch` packages, so the problem is not package specific.
- This the same `ECONNREFUSED` when making requests to public apis as well, so the problem is not specific to making requests to localhost
- Since the request is to localhost I think it should not be because of the company proxy. Is this a reasonable assumption?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have an environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` that contains an invalid proxy address.

If you're using Unix/Linux, try this:

```
env HTTP_PROXY= node yourscript.js
```

Comment: Executing env HTTP_PROXY= node index.js also resulted in ECONNREFUSED

Comment: If possible, try disabling your company proxy in the system settings to see if that solves the problem.